# Influence kernel function for Kernel Ridge Regression and Support Vector Regression

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn, kernel-trick

I am currently exploring two regression methods using kernels, namely Kernel Ridge Regression (KRR) and Support Vector Regression (SVR). I tune their parameters using a randomized grid search.

Using a polynomial kernel, KRR outperforms SVR, but when I use an rbf kernel it is the other way around.

What might be an intuitive explanation for this? Or should I interpret this as a specific trait of the dataset that I am analyzing?